# Radon-Nikodym derivative for the law of a process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are equivalent probability measures on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d \mathbb{Q}}{d \mathbb{P}}$. For any continuous stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t \geq 0}$, is it true that

> $$ \frac{d \mathbb{Q}}{d \mathbb{P}} = \frac{d \mathbb{Q_{X_t}}}{d \mathbb{P}_{X_t}}?$$
>   where $\mathbb{P_{X_t}}$ and $\mathbb{Q_{X_t}}$ denote the laws of $X_t$ under measures $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ respectively. If not, do we have an explicit formula for $\frac{d \mathbb{Q_{X_t}}}{d \mathbb{P}_{X_t}}$?

It is clear that
$$ \mathbb{Q_{X_t}}(A) = \mathbb{Q} (X_t \in A) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}} \Big[ \frac{d \mathbb{Q}}{d \mathbb{P}} \mathbf{1}_A (X_t) \Big].$$

But then it is not clear how to proceed as two random variables $\frac{d \mathbb{Q}}{d \mathbb{P}}$ and $X_t$ are involved... Any ideas?

Comment: (Versions of) these derivatives are not even functions on the same set, let alone equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assume, for definiteness, that $X_t$ is real valued.) Let $L$ denote $d\Bbb Q/d\Bbb P$. The $\Bbb P$-conditional expectation of $L$ with respect to $\sigma(X_t)$ can be written as $K_t\circ X_t$ for some Borel function $K_t:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$. You can now check that $K_t$ is a version of $d\Bbb Q_t/d\Bbb P_t$.